# javascript forEach check all elements true/false

Tags: javascript

I have a few classes

```
<div class="adiv"></div>
<div class="adiv"></div>
<div class="adiv cc"></div>
<div class="adiv"></div>
<div class="adiv"></div>

document.querySelectorAll('.adiv').forEach((v, i) => {
    console.log(v.classList.contains('cc'));
});
```

the result is 2 x false, 1 x true, 2 x false in order. The question is how to write something like below, how to check all together? please no jQuery. Many thanks

```
if (output is all true) return true else false?
```

Comment: Something like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.adiv')).every(`…`)`. Look up [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods.

Comment: Abstract outline: check each element, once you find one that yields `false` you can break out of the loop as you know that *not* all are `true`.

Comment: Or why not just `!document.querySelectorAll('.adiv.cc').length`?

Comment: @Xufox thanks for the answer! awesome!! short and clear

Comment: @Xufox, isn't that backwards? shouldn't it be `!document.querySelectorAll('.adiv:not(.cc)').length` given that the intent is to check that every `.adiv` element has a `.cc` class. There's a reason I avoid such shorthand notations. The intent behind the code gets masked and leads to confusion.

Comment: @zzzzBov You’re right, when writing the comment I assumed that it should check whether all should be `false` rather than `true`.

Comment: I return "true" if > 0, @zzzzBov thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check if every element in an array passes a predicate.

```
[1, 2, 3].every((num) => num > 0); // true
```

Because you're using `document.querySelectorAll`, you'll need to convert the array-like object it returns into an actual array.

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) for this.

Combined, you get:

```
allCC =
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.adiv'))
    .every((node) => node.classList.contains('cc'));
```

Comment: Nice. But `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.adiv')).every(...)` would be better due to Array.from browser support

Comment: @disstruct, there's a polyfill in the MDN documentation I linked to, and at this point `Array.from` has solid browser support with the [notable exception of IE](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Array_static_methods_Array.from,_array-like_objects).

Answer (score 0):

The `Array.from(`…`).every(`…`)` approach would work generally. There’s another quite elegant way in this case, though:

```
!document.querySelectorAll(".adiv:not(.cc)").length
```

This returns the negated length (`true` for `0`, `false` otherwise) of all elements where the class `adiv` appears without the class `cc`.

Another way:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".adiv").length == document.querySelectorAll(".adiv.cc").length
```

This compares the number of `.adiv` to the number of elements with both classes.